Pyspark: How to assign group-Level Flags Based on Presence of Employee Data in PySpark"
Let's suppose there are 10 records:

5 employees in DepartmentA: One of the guys in depA doesn't have net_income informarion (so has a null in there), 4 others do have it.
5 in DepB: In DepB every empl has net_inc info. So I want to have every_emp_net_inc_flag - and every employee in depA would get 0 - because not all of them have this info, one misses it. And in DepB they'd all get 1, because no one is missing this net income value.

The only idea I have is some sort of a window function that'd do something like this (I'd rewrite it to pyspark, but easier to explain in SQL):
SELECT
   employee_id,
   department,
   CASE
       WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY department) = COUNT(net_income) OVER (PARTITION BY department) 
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
   END AS every_emp_net_inc_flag
FROM
   employees;


And then I'd have df1 where flag = 1, and df2 where flag = 0.
I am trying to find a more elegant solution, but can't find any.
Thanks

Hi this can be implemented using a more efficient method like this
Create or replace temp view tbla as 
 Select department,
 Min(CASE WHEN net_income is null then 0 else 1 end) income_missing_flag 
  From employees group by department 

Now we will join this above temp view with the original table employees to have the flag
Select a.* ,b.income_missing_flag 
  From employees a left join tbla b 
 on a.department=b.department

